# Seem out to do something - meaning

Tags: idioms

Source: http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2014-04-04/putin-s-rejection-of-the-west-in-writing?cmpid=yhoo

> In fact, after Moscow's Crimean adventure, the West **seems out to prove** this point of view correct. By talking of "containing" Russia and breaking off all kinds of cooperation, from trade and visa liberation talks to Group of Eight meetings to joint programs with the National Aeronautics and Space Administration, Western governments cast themselves in the role of wolves shedding their sheep's clothing.

What does **the West seems out to prove this point** mean?

Comment: _(Be) out to `VP`_ is an idiom that means something like 'intend to `VP`'. If he's out to prove you wrong, he will try to prove you wrong. The _seem_ has nothing to do with it, except that _seem_ allows _to be_-deletion from the original infinitive _seems to be out to prove_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop the 'seem'; it is not part of the idiom.

'He is out to get me', for instance, means 'He has decided to do me harm (physical or otherwise)', 'He has purposed to harm me', or 'He has it in for me'.

The transitive multi-word verb be out to[+ infinitive; compare intend + to-infinitive + DO] is described [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/phrasal-verbs/be+out+to.html), though it is here called a 'phrasal verb':

> be out to
>
> Meaning: Attempt
>
> Example: She IS OUT TO get him sacked because she hates him.